# Converting set of points to solid object?

Tags: 3d, cad

I have a data generated as the output of some numerical processes. I need them to be converted into 3D solid objects (as CAD solid format) to make them importable for some particular numerical analysis software such as FEM. One initial stage is to do some Boolean operations on them. If they were is solid format it is OK, but the data is only coordinates and that's all!

The data set consist of points in which a set of points makes a particular shape say a cube. Each object has own associated points. If we draw lines between points of each object a proper object appears. These data need to be exported in 3D format consisting of only solid objects. Then a series of Boolean operations will apply.

So the questions are:

**How to convert such a data set to for example a *dxf* format consisting only *solid* objects?**

In particular purpose, **what is the structure** (format or so) **of a solid object in CAD** so we may write some simple code to convert our data set to solids?

*(Note that the data set is large so we need finally to do some programming in any language required.)*

Comment: Is there a 1:1 relationship between input points and output shape vertices or is this going to be a least-squares shape fitting sort of problem?

Comment: @WolfOdrade It is 1:1. That is each set of points makes a different object.

Comment: To respected curious readers: A good answer given [{here:StackOverFlow}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756208/cad-lines-to-solid-programmatically) technically based on Ruby language. It is really useful. If you're one looking for some starting point I would recommend that post. This post is here for future answers may consider solutions from different aspects.

Comment: That's cool!  I wish more GIS applications took advantage of Ruby, I really prefer it over Python.

Comment: @Developer could you please post your comment as an answer so this thread does not appear on the unanswered list anymore? Thanks!

Comment: @Developer It would be great if you could turn your comment into an answer in this case so that we can get this question off the 'unanswered' list. It seems to me that your reply fits the bill perfectly!

Comment: Please add sample data, or describe your data better. Is this very simple geometries, or complex geometries with hundreds of coordinates? Will try to elaborate my answer if you provide more background to your challenge.

Answer (score 1):

A solid  is built up by surfaces. The surfaces are again built up of lines which again are defined by two coordinates. Start by thinking about your data from the lowest level of the geometry model, then move upwards.

1. Isolate the relevant coordinates for your object. Since they are the output of a numerical process you might have an attribute which is relevant (group number, timestamp or other).
2. Aggregate external walls based on the relevant lines.
3. Build solids by using the [aggregator transformer](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/aggregator.htm) in [FME from Safe software](http://www.safe.com).
4. Export the objects using one of the many format writers in FME.

The question has similarities to building 3d objects from point cloud data. This could also be worth looking at.